# How to setup i686-elf cross-compiler on linux?

Tags: linux, bash, gcc, operating-system, bare-metal

When I was following the Bare Bones tutorial on the OSDev Wiki. I got the error:

```
i686-elf-as: command not found
```

I tried following the GCC Cross-compiler instructions when I run the command:

```
../binutils-x.y.z/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix="$PREFIX" --disable-nls --disable-werror
```

I got the error:

```
bash: ../binutils-x.y.z/configure: No such file or directory.
```

How can I setup my GCC cross-compiler to work with this tutorial?

Answer (score 9):

Replace `x.y.z` in the command with the binutils version.

Answer (score 2):

please follow the instructions:

- Linux:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/lordmilko/i686-elf-tools
$ cd i686-elf-tools
$ ./i686-elf-tools.sh linux
```

- macOS:
- make sure you have brew pre-installed

```
$ brew update
$ brew install i686-elf-gcc
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install 2 things in /home/src which is -

1. binutils-x.y.z (sometimes might not have z, and just can be x.y)
2. under /src create a folder called "build-binutils". You need to cd to build binutils later on and there use the commande - "./binutils-x.y.z/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix="$PREFIX" --disab".......................
3. Note - you might get error that the address is not absolute.... in this case... take root access (by doing sudo su on shell) and then, go to folder binutils-x.y.z and check if there is any file by name "configure".... If there is one, all the commands mentioned above should work !

This is how the directory looks -

|src|
---->binutilsx.y.z
---->build-binutils

Again, You will cd into build-binutils and execute the command which you mentioned above ( this one ../binutils-x.y.z/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix="$), but before that will check whether the folder 'binutilsx.y.z' has a configure file ( you do it by changing to root user )... and if it is there...  the commands should work fine..

if you are unable to see the 'configure' file ( NOTICE - the configure might have different name - configure.ac or just configure )... then may be you need to install different version of binutils-x.y.1.1.2. etc